# Customer Session

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, session

I am using the Magento customer session to store some data. I want it to be destroyed when a customer logs out.

However (customer/session) still persisting the data.

One way is I can unset data on the log-out observer. But does it automatically clear all the customer session data when the user logs out?

What is the ideal way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

These are your options, they do all the same, clearing all data on the session. <strike>But when the customer logs out, there is no way to retrieve the data, because the session is destroyed.</strike>

```
$customerSession->unset()
$customerSession->clear()
$customerSession->unsetAll()
```

Calling one of the methods on logout event `customer_logout` is a good idea.